# Adding Layer from CSV cuts Milliseconds from string using QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, addlayer

I am using QGIS 3.22.11.

When adding a layer from a CSV source. It carries a hand full of attributes where one attribute column 'Time' having entries like 12:56:37.876 (string format --> hh:mm:ss.000) the milliseconds will be cut after adding the data to the layers, even though the time is shown correctly in the preview.

I tried several ways importing it, but almost nothing kept the the milliseconds.

Workarounds:

a) Creating a column adding leading a 'T_' to the time making it a string like T_12:56:37.876.
--> successful import.

b) Creating a PyQgis Script creating a spatial or non-spatial layer via code iterating over an imported Pandas DataFrame of the exact same data-source.
--> successful import

All other approaches using a regular time with milliseconds failed via the "add Layer / from CSV"-dialog with CSVs stored with Excel, Notepad++ as csv(comma separated) and/or txt(\t separated)

Is this behavior by purpose or by accident?

I would expect to get data into QGIS like they are displayed in the preview, and not a cut or randomly formatted version of the preview which might or might not be correct.

I tried this on two different computers windows 10, with QGIS 3.22.11 desktop with the same result.

Comment: Do you happen to have the option `Detect Field Types` checked? That's the only way I could reproduce your issue. With it unchecked, the milliseconds were maintained in my testing.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue and makes live less complicating! On the other hand  I would expect that the detection of a time format shoudn't cut numbers, and the question about accident or purpose remains.

Comment: I agree, it is rather strange behaviour.

Comment: Probably somewhere in the QGIS code the QTime https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtime.html is defined to use time without fractional seconds.